# jQuery buttons aren't clickable on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have a jQuery scroll div on [this site](http://www.gabrielewebdesigner.it/work_site/bksny/), but the buttons to go up and down don't work on iPad. I used [this plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) (the first on left) and I tryed various scripts and solutions, but I can't to fix this problem. Please, have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Does the plugin demo page work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jQuery mobile?

```
$(id).tap(function(){
   // call your appropriate scroll event
});
```

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html